# delete friend from friend list (graph api)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Spring Social Facebook (Java) to call Graph API methods for friend lists, using an app-specific access_token that contains all available permissions.

I can create a list and add members to it. But when I want to remove a member, 
    DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/{LIST_ID}/members/{USER_ID}?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
...the call fails with a 400 error.

I tried calling the same 'delete' URL from my own java client code (Jersey) and got the same 400 error:
400 Bad Request
    Method Not Implemented
    Invalid method in request

But the same 'delete' URL works no problem if I use it:
  - in the Graph API debug tool
  - in the "RESTClient" Firefox extension

Any ideas why the java code is having trouble with this delete call?

Comment: any luck with this? i just hit the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a batch request (even for a single call) and it worked fine. Probably a bug.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/